# Hightlight cells where the IFERROR=TRUE; Not "TRUE". Suggestions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

Example:

Formula: `IFERROR(H12,1)`

Table:

[image: Example Table]

I am trying to highlight every cell in the table that returns a 1 **only** if the `IFERROR` statement is TRUE (not "TRUE"), and without comparing the returned value of that specific cell to a cell in another row/column. I don't want to use conditional formatting to highlight every cell that =1, because some of those 1's may not be the result of an `IFERROR=TRUE`.

Is there a way to do this with a conditional formatting formula, or should I use VBA script? If VBA, example script would be much appreciated as I am new to VBA.

Comment: What is the content of column H?

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula in conditional formatting, in format values where this formula is True write:

> =ISERROR(H12)=TRUE

and Highlight as you wish.

Comment: This suggests that I would have to specify each individual well that has an error instead of formatting the table based on the values that are derived from the table itself. The problem with that is that I would like to use this table as a template for other data, and the wells will not always match up, meaning that I will need to go through and adjust this every time I use this spreadsheet, making it not much of a template at all. Any suggestions on how to format the table based on the TRUE/FALSE output from the table without having to specify which specific cells have the ERROR?